# Suspiciously wrong value by factor of $1/2$ in experiment to calculate frequency of AC mains using sonometer

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, electric-current

In school we performed the following experiment:
[image]

We use a step down transformer ($220V$ to $6V$) and pass current through a "sonometer wire". We have a meter scale underneath the wire. There is a horseshoe/bar magnet placed over the wire such that it creates magnetic field perpendicular to the current in the wire. At one end of the wire we hang slotted weights to create tension ($T$) in the wire. There are two wedges on either end of the magnet. Now due to the perpendicular magnetic field there is a force on the current carrying wire, and the force direction alternates with frequency of AC due to changing direction of current. We slowly move these wedges outwards together until the length between the wedges is such that the fundamental frequency of standing waves in that wire equals the frequency of AC and thus the frequency of oscillations of the wire. At this point it vibrates with large amplitude and we can see it clearly. Here we take the distance between the wedges ($L$). Finally we can calculate the frequency of AC mains using

$$f = \frac{1}{2L}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$
where $\mu$ is the mass per unit length of the wire.
I did this experiment myself where the wire had linear mass density $0.008$ kg/m (value given by teacher, didn't measure it myself) and with a $0.5$ kg weight and I got $L$ as $51.6$ cm. Obviously something is wrong because this gives me a frequency close to $25$ Hz and in my country it is $50$ Hz. The fact that it's off by a factor of 2 is suspicious.

**Note**: I performed it multiple times with different slotted weights ranging from half a kilo to 2 kilos, got a variety of lengths from roughly half a meter to ~$70-80$ cm, and each time got a frequency close to half the actual value.

I did some research and found out that this experiment is also sometimes done using an electromagnet (here we use a wire of *magnetic material*) instead of a bar magnet, where due to the magnetization of the electromagnet, the wire is attracted to and then released towards the electromagnet **twice in each cycle** of AC and here we will see oscillations of the wire of large amplitude when the length of wire is adjusted such that the AC mains frequency matches with the wire's resonant frequency.

Here the frequency of oscillation of the wire is twice the frequency of AC, so the frequency of AC will be given by

$$f = \frac{1}{4L}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$$

which is half the resonant frequency. However this is clearly not the issue in my case because:
a) it is a different experiment, and
b) my answer was off by a factor of $1/2$ not $2$

Also: today my physics teacher told me that the distance between the wedges itself is supposed to be $2L$ not $L$, although this makes no sense to me because that doesn't seem to be consistent with what I know about standing waves between two fixed ends, since obviously $\lambda = 2L$ for the fundamental mode.

Sorry for the long question and possibly unnecessary information; I just want to know if there is something else to this, because my current best guess is that the mass per unit length is wrong.

Comment: And here I was thinking the factor of two would be the other way - an incandescent or fluorescent bulb turns on/off at twice the mains frequency.

Comment: Yup that's the same as the case I described with the electromagnet, not sure what's going on with my experiment though

Comment: And how many nodes and antinodes did you count?

Comment: Just in case,   $\dots$ I would measure the mass per unit length of the sonometer wire.

Comment: @Pizzaguy07 1 antinode at the center and 2 nodes at the wedges. Unfortunately, there was certainly no node at the center indicating the 2nd mode of vibration as I was hoping.

Comment: @Farcher My school doesn't have/provide us weighing machines that precise/sensitive. But if I can't find any other issue I'll be forced to assume that is the source of error.

Comment: If you can measure the diameter of the wire and know the material that it is made of you can look up the density and then estimate the mass per unit length?

Comment: Ok thanks I'll do that the next time I'm in the lab!